# Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, gnome-classic

This particular version of the "doesn't work after suspend" came after upgrading to 16.04. It seems that the upgrade includes a Wicd applet (added to Metacity Classic Gnome task bar alongside regular network icon), but doesn't seem to work after a suspend. A `sudo service network-manager restart` duplicates this problem. It takes a complete reboot to get Wifi going again. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you file a bug at launchpad for the problem ???

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpasupplicant/+bug/1556357

Comment: Looks like this problem has been around [since Ubuntu 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: This never happened under 14.04 LTS for me. The upgrade to 16.04 LTS is so great I'll keep it, but it keeps forgetting my WiFi password.  The service is clearly running; just that it forgets the password and doesn't connect.  I posted this:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/934958/how-to-make-ubuntu-16-04-lts-remember-my-wifi-password-through-a-shutdown - and I do not want to deal with blacklisting or anything strange.

Comment: ... And the problem is still there in Ubuntu 20. I'm kinda fed up at this point.

Answer (score 187):

16.04 runs on systemd. Try the following:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

If this works, you can create a script to automate it.

Open a terminal and type the following:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service` Now paste the script in there with a right click. Exit with CTRL + X and press Y to save. Now to activate it: `sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service`

Script:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart networkmanager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

Hope this helps. It works on my laptop.

Comment: Yes, that correction didn't error out, but it's still not working. Again, I have two icons in my panel, side-by-side, one for the usual network, one is wicd. I didn't have wicd there before. Are they clashing. BTW, my KDE Plasma doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to simply uninstall wicd?

Comment: Uninstalled, but problem persists. Now I have just the original network icon, but still no connection (doesn't see wifi hotspots) possibilities after coming back from suspend.

Comment: Did you create a /home partition, if so, I would reinstall, instead of upgrade, to be honest. Not really a solution, but often fixes these things.

Comment: I would say don't bother reinstalling for this. I did a clean install and I'm running into this issue on 16.04. Never had a problem with 14.04.

Comment: @JoakimKoed please edit your answer to use the lower-case version of the command at the very beginning

Comment: the command: sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
works but not the script.

Comment: @tokam the script is running after each time you resume from sleep. That is when I had issues. Are you running 16.04?

Comment: Yes it appears to be working now fine

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes not :(

Comment: @tokam sorry it's not working for you all the time. It works perfect for me. Lets hope they get these nasty bugs fixed soon.

Comment: It's Not Work for me.

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates what is not working? The script or the first command?

Comment: @JoakimKoed None of the solutions work to me., thanks in advances. I use Kubuntu 16.04 - asus republic of gamers.

Comment: I assume you mean neither things? Anyway, this will only work IF you have some problems after suspend. If it's not working at all maybe do a post yourself and ask for help.. Remember to provide logs, your wifi card etc.

Comment: Sometimes your command fixes the issue, sometimes not. Also the script does not fix the issue sometimes. My main problem is, that I am online, but this information is not spread among NM-Applet and Evolution. So I can not download E-Mails because Evolution does not even try when it thinks that the system is offline. Now after running your command a restart of evolution helped.

Comment: @takan: seems you have a deeper problem :(

Comment: which one? how to find that out? I have an own thread for this, which was guided to the one here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/767878/networkmanager-does-not-know-that-i-am-online-after-resuming-from-hibernate?noredirect=1#comment1147389_767878

Comment: For me only running `/etc/init.d/network-manager restart` fix the problem, should I put it in a script like you did? (the systemctl command doesn't work for me)

Comment: @elichai2 Then you are not running 16.04 or anything with systemd. The script is really made for systemd. See something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Do you think some part of the Ubuntu network stack is still using the upstart command? Perhaps there is another place in the init system that executes the old command and replacing it with the systemd equivalent can fix the problem at the source rather than stemming another Unit on the end. This would be good for a bug report on Launchpad if so and it could affect other systems.

Comment: @mikeymop I have been thinking this as well. I know some parts of the system is still using upstart, so that might trigger something. Since 16.10 is full systemd and does not have the error, you might be correct.

Comment: I've been testing a [variation of this](https://gist.github.com/nitely/3d5f10b4f686f5f96c95) for the past week, and it restarts the network flawlessly. No more Wi-Fi problems.

Comment: @JoakimKoed This works perfectly for me. Is there a way to temporarily disable this for a period of time to see if it is still necessary? What is the proper way to reverse this work around?

Comment: @Dennis sudo systemctl disable wifi-resume.service

Comment: This worked wonders for me. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an MSI GP60 and after resuming from suspension it would connect to my wifi but it didn't show the wifi channel I was connected to or any available wifi channels.

Comment: How can I remove this, this won't work on my system

Comment: The script in this answer seems to work just fine for me. I've used it on two X1 Carbons, one 2nd generation and one 4th, and it has helped a great deal. Thanks!

Comment: Also try NetworkManager.service if network-manager.service fails.

Comment: Tried only resuming at the command line. It works. Will check if the issue ever shows up again.

Comment: Script is not working for me. "Wifi Disabled" is shown in my networks, I have realtek RTL8723be driver

Comment: This has worked on Ubuntu 16.10 with my Dell XPS 15 9550 (it has some DNS problems after suspend/resume, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1673796 ) Thanks!

Comment: this has worked on Ubuntu 16.04.2(Acer E15)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work consistent on my XPS 9550 Ubuntu 16.04. Manual restart with the same command works like a charm though. I will add asleep command similar to a suggestion in another post and test it for a while. Another problem that was also mentioned here is that a network applet disappears from the panel and I don't know how to return it. It would be really nice to have(restart unity-panel-service doesn't help).

Comment: Thanks for making a script for us. But it doesnt run on resume for me. If i go and run "sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service"  manually, it fixes the problem however.

Comment: The command "sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service" always works for me, but the script does not work. I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 27):

@147pm Did you ever get this working?

I found I had a quite similar problem, though I am on Kubuntu 16.10 (KDE-based, not Gnome), and with an HP ProBook laptop. And, unlike yourself, it wasn't my Wifi which died after suspend/wakeup, but my ethernet port.
Still, I wonder if they are related.

I also do see that you do not have the problem under KDE. But I would be interested to know if the solution below does help under Gnome, as the solution is not based upon window manager, desktop environment or applets.

First, just to confirm that restarting the network manager service..

```
$ sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

did not work for me.

However, I did find an answer that worked, thanks to buzhidao's question and info at [can't connect to internet after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855699/cant-connect-to-internet-after-suspend) and GAD3R's comment there.

Using their info, I found that first researching which ethernet hardware and driver/module I am running, and then removing and reloading that module, did work for me (though it did not for buzhidao):

Wifi:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Ethernet:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Ether -A2
```

The second of these (ethernet) was what I used, and I found:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:1944]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

so i reloaded the 'r8169' driver:

```
$ sudo rmmod r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169
```

and voila! This worked.  My ethernet port / connection came back alive (after suspend/wakeup) without having to reboot.

(I also did NOT have a Realtek wifi device, but a Qualcomm Atheros (mod: ath9k) which perhaps explains why wifi continued to work for me after wake-from-suspend.)

As you can see from my comment on that other post, I wondered whether the problem is the common element between Buzhidao and myself: Realtek Semiconductor devices. Even though they use different modules, they might share some common code? Or even be treated differently by the newer kernel code now in some way?

Do you yourself have a Realtek-based wifi device? (using lspci above)?  Do you have any luck re-installing the module (rmmod/modprobe above)?

Anyway, just a shot in the dark. If you have found an eventual answer for yourself, please let us know! Thx.

Comment: I also have a RTL8111/8168/8411 ethernet and `sudo rmmod r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169` solved the problem.

Comment: Same issue on Debian 9 with KDE. Reinstalling as above fixed it. Thanks a ton.

Comment: My computer* too has a RTL8111/8168/8411 ethernet device and `sudo rmmod r8169 && sudo modprobe r81691` finally fixed the issue for me. Didn't have this problem before kernel version 4.16.

(*Debian 10 with GNOME, Kernel 4.16, and [proprietary firmware from Realtek](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-realtek))

Comment: worked for me archlinux with ath10k_pci

Comment: re-insert kern module fixed for me on xub 19.10. Interestingly, this issue started only recently, didn't happen on 19.04 or older for me. I'm on t420.

Comment: Reloading the module also worked for my `ath10k_pci` wifi adapter. It had worked smoothly until some update. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel `5.4.0-37-generic #41`

Comment: Had the same issue and so needed this! Different driver on Debian Buster, same fix.

Comment: This problem persists into U 20 and this solution worked for me (the others did NOT).  Thanks!

Comment: same here with a macbook pro early 2015 and ubuntu 19, I didn't want to install a different broadcom driver because honestly it mostly works fine, but this was the fix I needed for waking up from a long sleep (maybe hibernation?)

Comment: Thanks! On my Ubuntu 20.10 it was `rtw88_8822ce` that had to be reloaded (Network controller: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe wireless network adapter).

Comment: Going to save this, so useful!!

Comment: Thank You very much
Was trying many other solutions for hours finally yours worked on my Ubuntu 20.04 :)

Comment: Finally it works. Tried many other solutions with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To auto-restart NetworkManager after resume in an environment without `sudo` access, create a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` (any name), set the executable bit via `chmod +x`, and insert the following content:

```
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
        # systemctl restart network-manager.service
        service NetworkManager restart
;;
esac
```

For me, the `service` line worked, but `systemctl` may work better for you.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/92235/30266.

Comment: The `service NetworkManager restart` worked for me, but the placement of the script did not (on 16.04). I had to move the script to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/script-name-here`. In this case the first argument to the script is `[pre |  post]`, so I had to change the case statement to `case "${1}" in ... post) ...`. I also wrapped the inner statement in `case "${2}" in ... suspend) ...`.

Comment: Should be `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` for 15.04+

Answer (score 3):

For me it seems to be random, but sometimes the wifi just disconnects if I'm connected, or doesn't show networks if I'm not. Sometimes putting my laptop into sleep mode seems to trigger it, but not always.

Some combination of these usually gets it going again without rebooting:

- `sudo iwlist $(ifconfig | grep -Po '^w\w+') scan`
- `sudo service network-manager stop; sleep 5; sudo service network-manager start`

  - Simply calling `restart` here never seems to work for me. It looks like it tries to start it up before it's finished shutting it down, hence I have more luck pausing between `stop` and `start`.
- Turn off wifi in UI; wait a few seconds; turn it back on

None of those seems to consistently work, but I listed them in order of most-likely-to-succeed first.

Comment: Also for me `restart` didn't work but `stop` and `start` did! No other answer worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Working method on Ubuntu 16.04:

Create the service: `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service`

The service is calling the program from:
**/etc/init.d/network-manager**

Paste the code:

```
#/lib/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart network-manager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

Then enable the service:

`sudo systemctl enable /lib/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service`

This creates the symlinks into the indicated [Install] directories of /etc/systemd/system and activates the service

Afterwards you can check the status with: `systemctl status wifi-resume.service`

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands one by one in the terminal.

1.`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix`
2. Paste the below code and save it.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
     case "$1" in
             pre) true ;;
             post) sleep 1 && service network-manager restart ;;
       esac
fi
```

3. `sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix`

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04. It works on other Mint and Elementary versions as well.

I got the solution from [here](https://letsfoss.com/fix-wifi-not-working-after-suspend-in-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with bluetooth: After suspend my bluetooth mouse did not work. So I derived the solution from above:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth-resume.service
```

enabled the new service

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth-resume.service
```

and edited the service

```
#/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable bluetooth-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart bluethooth at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart bluetooth.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

I also tried to edit ...

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

and changed

```
AutoEnable=true
```

BUT this did NOT work for the "resume problem" and had no inmpact on new bluetooth devices anyhow!

Comment: How does this post answer the OP?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my laptop Dell Inspiron 15R with Ubuntu 16.04. For me worked [the script reported on the second reply](https://askubuntu.com/q/761180/#comment1186026_761180).

After having installed the script I tried the suspension with the command in the upper right menu and even closing the lip, solving the problem.

I have to say that the problem was alternating in its behaviour (that is, sometimes it worked before installing the script).

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to run

```
nmcli nm sleep false
```

in a terminal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue connecting back to my home wifi after suspend. Tried the various other suggested answers which would occasionally work but not always.

Eventually the following fix allowed for consistently connecting to the wifi:

1) Edit this file:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

2) By adding this to it:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Answer (score 0):

Now probably simple

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

should work.

In my case among upgraded packages there was `bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.3)` and after this update wifi works again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried the solutions above which didn't work for my intel 6235 adapter.

Random websearches instead led me to the solution:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Which resolves the problem until next suspend.