# Mobile net ubuntu 16.04 wifi icon

Tags: icons, broadband

In Ubuntu 16.04 when I'm connected to mobile broadband connection, the icon still signs that I'm not connected. It's a little bit annoying and it's a minor problem, but it would be great if it signs correctly the connection.

It's not a crash so i don't know how to report that problem. Anyone has this same issue or any idea to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This related I believe to another known bug in Ubuntu 16.04, with many others affected. Most also do not have connection icons after Resume from Suspend, or no connection at all!

See here; [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)

See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1448555

You can also just restart Network Manager.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I hope a fix comes out soon.