# No WiFi ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't connect to any network!

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, connection, lts

I had always this problem when the notebook was suspended. But normally with a reboot everything goes right, but not now! Can someone help me?

After done `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:6627]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Instead of rebooting you can restart NM by `sudo service network-manager restart`. This is an old bug. There is no good fix.

Comment: I just tried with that command and the results it's the same

Comment: I also tried to use sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service but nothing

Comment: Does Wi-Fi work after this command? For me it always helps on many laptops.

Comment: Nope, i tried with both :-(

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A2`.

Comment: @DhavalSimaria just viewed that post and did not work for me

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade @GiovanniGiampaolo this link might  ease out your problem

Comment: @JonasCz Done ;)