# Killer 1535 Wireless Won't Resume From Suspend

Tags: wireless, suspend

So, I managed to get my Killer 1535 wifi working in Ubuntu 16.04. However, there seems to be a nagging problem that everytime I suspend my laptop, on wake-up the wifi adapter is not available.

A full restart and/or shutdown and re-start, however, makes it available again!

Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade/761220#761220

Comment: No luck, man! Still shows "No Network Device Available" when I click the wifi icon. A restart brings it back up!

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Where did you download the firmware from?

Comment: Then I'm not sure, never had such a wifi card. Seems is atheros though, maybe try a newer kernel? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Does it restart if you do: `sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: It is an Atheros card, Killer 1535. I got the latest firmware package using:



 `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb |||
    
    sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb |||
    
 sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pco`

Yes,  `sudo service network-manager restart` does, in fact, restart the adapter. But it still tells me No Network Device Available.

Comment: Any updates on this front? Linux Mint 18 has this problem too. I know Mint is based on Ubuntu, but the system error I have had in Ubuntu 16.04 that would cause an infinite loop in the log in screen after a log out is non-existent in  Mint 18.