# Internet doesn't be connected after suspend through VPN with WiFi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, vpn

Wifi can resumed but it doesn't connect to Internet through OpenVPN with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Wireless through VPN? That doesn't work (though the other way around would) and I'm sure we have a misunderstanding about your networking setup. Can you please [edit] your question and clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openvpn doesn't properly work after suspend. it needs restart.

`sudo service openvpn restart`

Actually, I wanted to leave a comment in the below question, but I don't have enough rep. So I decided to answer my question. This will help somebody having the same problem.

[Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)