# can't connect to internet after suspend

Tags: networking, 16.04, suspend

### description of the problem

It seems both wifi and ethernet has the same problem. However, it seems it only happens when the suspend time is long. If I close lid for about 5 min or so, it is OK. However when I suspend for hours, when coming back, I can't connect to the internet. I have tried:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service 
sudo service network-manager restart 
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

None of them helps, even log out. The only way to resume the network is by a restart.

I found some post on the web such as this one:  [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade), but it doesn't help even there are so many vote ups, therefore I think it is OK to ask this question again to draw some attention and hopefully my problem can be solved.

#### Edit

```
-> ~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8195]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

Comment: After resuming run `sudo rmmod rtl8192ce && sudo modprobe  rtl8192ce` if  it  work  there are a script to set it auto

Comment: @GAD3R Next time I will try it when it won't work.

Comment: @GAD3R this method doesn't working.

Comment: i was having the problem too (on 16.10 on an HP), but w/ethernet dead after suspend.  Running my own version of buzhidao's suggestion (~$ lspci -knn | grep Ether -A2) i learned i had a:  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c), using the r8169 kernel module. When i re-installed the module (as per GAD3R above), my ethernet revived.  Since buzhidao's & my devices are both Realtek Semiconductor devices (but his is wifi, mine ethernet), i am wondering whether some code common to both realtek drivers has changed?

Answer (score 2):

Lifted from 
[Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/893823/366935)

I found that first researching which ethernet hardware and driver/module I am running, and then removing and reloading that module, did work for me (though it did not for buzhidao):

Wifi:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Ethernet:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Ether -A2
```

The second of these (ethernet) was what I used, and I found:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:1944]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

so i reloaded the 'r8169' driver:

```
$ sudo rmmod r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169
```

and voila! This worked. My ethernet port / connection came back alive (after suspend/wakeup) without having to reboot.

**in my case the driver was different, but the same commands `rmmod` and `modprobe` did the trick**