# WiFi signal icon switches to Ethernet icon (up down arrows) after Suspend?

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, suspend, ethernet

When I wake my laptop up after being suspended for a little while, the WiFi signal gets replaced by up and down arrows. The connection still works, but is rather annoying nonetheless. Restarting the Network Manager works, but is only a temporary fix.

I read somewhere that it might be because the connection is getting renamed, thus causing it to think I'm connected via Ethernet instead of WiFi?

How can I fix this?

Edit: I've noticed that this also happens on occasion after turning WiFi on/off.

Comment: That bug was fixed a while ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1576726

Comment: @AndroidDev Well, it still happens to me. I skimmed through that, but didn't see any sort of solution.

Comment: @M_W: Many fixed bugs happens later to some users like [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1640970) one.

Comment: My problem started occurring a few weeks ago and it is the reverse of yours. I have Realtek r8169 driver loaded for ethernet (up and down arrows) but after suspend the Intel N-2230 WiFi card gets activated instead. A script to restart it after resuming didn't work so I have to manually call a script to `rmmod r8169` and `insmod r8169`.

Comment: That bug report has nothing to do with this. Maybe file or see if one specific to issue has been filed. Wicd works fine after suspend, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Comment: I believe you are affected by [this unassigned bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1060167) I recommend that you subscribe to it so that you can be notified when it's squashed and so that the developers can prioritize their time. I'm sorry I don't have a solution but hopefully this will put you on the right track.

Comment: This is a confirmed unassigned [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1636282)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Automatic Method

Using sudo powers create the file `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/iwlwifi-reset` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

# NAME: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/iwlwifi-reset
# DESC: Resets Intel WiFi after a long suspend.
# DATE: Apr 1, 2017. Modified April 8, 2017.

# NOTE: Per AU comment restart network.

MYNAME=$0

restart_wifi() {
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi BEGIN'
#    /sbin/modprobe -v -r iwldvm # This removes iwlwifi too
#    /sbin/modprobe -v iwlwifi   # This starts iwldvm too
    systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi END'
}

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1}' ]'
case "${1}/${2}" in
    hibernate|suspend|pre*)
      ;;
    resume|thaw|post*)
      restart_wifi;;
esac
```

Mark the script as executable using:

```
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/iwlwifi-reset
```

To check execution of the script after waking up from suspend use:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep iwlwifi
```

Don't get too excited if it seems to work during testing because there are times when this script works with a short suspend but doesn't work after a long suspend.

If this doesn't work, before trying the **Manual Method** in the next section, place the command `sleep 5` before the line `restart_wifi;;`.

## Manual Method

If the automatic method isn't working using sudo powers create the script `/usr/local/bin/iwlwifi-reset` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

# NAME: /usr/lib/bin/iwlwifi-reset
# DESC: Manually reset Intel WiFi.
# DATE: Apr 1, 2017. Modified April 8, 2017.
# NOTE: Must call using SUDO POWERS.

MYNAME=$0

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi BEGIN'
# modprobe -r iwldvm    # This removes iwlwifi too
# modprobe iwlwifi      # This starts iwldvm too
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi END'
```

Mark the script as executable using:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/iwlwifi-reset
```

As described in the last section you can check **/var/log/syslog** for messages when this script is run but you will see any error messages in your terminal anyway.

To call this script use:

```
sudo iwlwifi-reset
```

You don't need to specify the directory because `/usr/local/bin` is in the terminal's command search path.

---

**Edit April 8, 2017** As per OP comment and [this How-To](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-network-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux), revisions to script were made. Instead of removing and reinserting kernel modules, restarting network services were used.

Comment: the file creation path & chmod path aren't the same, you'd likely want to fix that in your post..

Comment: Setting it to just restart the NetworkService appears to be working so far.
Using modprobe caused connection issues.

Comment: @M_W Thanks for your comment. I've revised the scripts and included a link to various methods of restarting network services from the common to most obscure.

Comment: Well it's looking like there's no other solution aside from an official bug fix, and although this is a workaround, it appears to be working just fine. +50

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also with my HP pavilon G6, which didn't really start until I got a new usb adaptor and plugged it in. After some searching I figured out that the wrong drivers were being used so I installed the correct drivers (Ralink) and it worked out. You didn't mention that you had a second adaptor but maybe checking to see what modprobe returns will help.

I got the idea from the last answer in this thread: [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)

Comment: My WiFi adapter is "Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230".

It appears to be running the iwlwifi driver:
"driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-45-generic"

Maybe Intel has a specific driver like they do for their graphics... will do some checking.

Comment: I found this, but it appears that I already have the same .ucode file located in my /lib/firmware folder.

https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html