# wifi not working after sleep/suspend

Tags: wireless, network-manager, suspend

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, my wifi was working perfectly but around one month ago every time after suspending the session my wifi doesn't work anymore, although the wifi-interface confirms that the connection has been established.
The command

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

works fine, but I must call it every time I get back from suspending, and it's kind of annoying.

I followed the instructions of [wifi still sleeping when resume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748113/wifi-still-sleeping-when-resume/748130?noredirect=1#comment1413928_748130), but unfortunately the proposed solution fails in my case when calling

```
sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
```

returning "command not found".
How could I generate a script to fix this problem?

More info on my wireless can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24334731/

Comment: The executable should be located in /bin/systemctl and be able to run without specifying the full path. It is part of the systemd package which comes preinstalled with 16.04. Please show the output of `apt policy systemd` to verify you have the necessary package installed.

Comment: @chili555 here you are with the output you requested:
`systemd:
 Installed: 229-4ubuntu16
 Candidate: 229-4ubuntu16
  Version table:
 *** 229-4ubuntu16 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: How about: `ls -al /bin/systemctl` I wonder if you have a permissions issue.

Comment: @chili555 that's what i get: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 659848 janv. 18 23:04 /bin/systemctl`

Comment: I wonder if you have a 'path' issue, about which I know little. I will propose a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: The answer here would work for you too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/898297/wifi-signal-icon-switches-to-ethernet-icon-up-down-arrows-after-suspend/899304#899304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both systemd and systemctl seem to be correct. However, to try to help solve your issue, please try:

```
sudo -i
/bin/systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
exit
```

Please post any errors or warnings.

Comment: I just tried again with the instructions of your answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/748113/wifi-still-sleeping-when-resume/748130?noredirect=1#comment1413928_748130 and this time it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the present case, after coming out of sleep my wifi was rfkill-blocked (normally this doesnt happen) and it only had to be unblocked.

(sidenote: I found out after trying to manually bring up the wifi interface with `sudo ip link set wlp6s0 up` -> output was: `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`)

**solution was:**

```
rfkill list       # (to show all interfaces, if anyone has soft or hard-block "yes" it cant be used)
# output:
#   2: phy0: Wireless LAN
#      Soft blocked: no
#      Hard blocked: no
sudo rfkill unblock wlan    # you can use the number or the name/category, see `man rfkill`
```

after unblocking (maybe check again with `rfkill list`), wifi was working again

Comment: Also worked on Debian based distribution with no network-manager present

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I "fixed" it with `sudo ifconfic <wireless_card> up` evey time I suspend the computer. It's not perfect, but it works eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with "enable Airplane Mode" and disabling it again.  Wireless connection started to resume.  Hope this helps.