# (Yet another) Wifi issue after suspend in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, suspend

I'm posting here as having troubles with the wifi after suspend.

I recently bought a new pcie wifi card (TP-LINK TL-WN881N), and it all works great. Unfortunately, it seems things turn bad when I put my computer to sleep, as the wifi doesn't work properly after waking up.

In face, the problem is weird. It does connect to the wifi network, connection is showed in nm-applet, connection seems alright in ifconfig, routes are fine, but it seems the drivers gets in a buggy mode where I cannot even ping (or reach in anyway) my gateway or any other location.

I tried different fixes, like the one here [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade) or here [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04) and none of them worked.
The weirdest thing is, if I try to manually restart the network-manager service, things don't get solved and instead I even get troubles listing the wifi networks. A reboot seems like the only way to solve the problem so far.

Here are some details about my card and driver:

```
$sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 30:b4:9e:72:08:78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ee driverversion=4.10.0-32-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7103fff
```

Thanks!

edit:

Solved! Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix, it seems that by applying a similar method than the one described here [WiFi signal icon switches to Ethernet icon (up down arrows) after Suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898297/wifi-signal-icon-switches-to-ethernet-icon-up-down-arrows-after-suspend/899304#899304), I managed to solve the problem.

The conditions were not exactly the same, and I had to adapt the solution. Basically, restarting network-manager doesn't fix the problem, but unloading the reloading the kernel module worked!
So here is how I adapted the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh                                                                                     

# NAME: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-reset                                                  
# DESC: Resets Realtek WiFi after a long suspend.                                             
# DATE: Aug 25, 2017. Modified Aug 25, 2017.                                                  

MYNAME=$0                                                                                     

DRIVER=rtl8192ee                                                                              

restart_wifi() {                                                                              
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi BEGIN'                                              
    /sbin/modprobe -v -r $DRIVER # This removes the driver                                    
    /sbin/modprobe -v $DRIVER   # This starts the driver                                      
    #systemctl restart NetworkManager.service # network manager restart disabled as not needed
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi END'                                                
}                                                                                             

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1}' ]'                                                     
case "${1}/${2}" in                                                                           
    hibernate|suspend|pre*)                                                                   
    ;;                                                                                        
    resume|thaw|post*)                                                                        
        restart_wifi;;                                                                        
esac
```

It works perfectly now :)

Thanks guys!

Comment: There are more than two threads on this subject. eg: https://askubuntu.com/questions/898297/wifi-signal-icon-switches-to-ethernet-icon-up-down-arrows-after-suspend/899304#899304

Comment: You are welcome but as muru states it is best to have an answer posted and accepted .

Comment: alright, that's missing in the warning when clicking on "answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

Solved! Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix, it seems that by applying a similar method than the one described here [WiFi signal icon switches to Ethernet icon (up down arrows) after Suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898297/wifi-signal-icon-switches-to-ethernet-icon-up-down-arrows-after-suspend/899304#899304), I managed to solve the problem.

The conditions were not exactly the same, and I had to adapt the solution. Basically, restarting network-manager doesn't fix the problem, but unloading the reloading the kernel module worked!
So here is how I adapted the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh                                                                                     

# NAME: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-reset                                                  
# DESC: Resets Realtek WiFi after a long suspend.                                             
# DATE: Aug 25, 2017. Modified Aug 25, 2017.                                                  

MYNAME=$0                                                                                     

DRIVER=rtl8192ee                                                                              

restart_wifi() {                                                                              
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi BEGIN'                                              
    /sbin/modprobe -v -r $DRIVER # This removes the driver                                    
    /sbin/modprobe -v $DRIVER   # This starts the driver                                      
    #systemctl restart NetworkManager.service # network manager restart disabled as not needed
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi END'                                                
}                                                                                             

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1}' ]'                                                     
case "${1}/${2}" in                                                                           
    hibernate|suspend|pre*)                                                                   
    ;;                                                                                        
    resume|thaw|post*)                                                                        
        restart_wifi;;                                                                        
esac
```

It works perfectly now :)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with a few differences though.

My laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad T470s running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (xenial).

After suspending and resuming, I had the following behavior:

- the network manager would restart, and the list of wifi networks would be ok,
- it would not make any difference whether the PC had been suspended for a short or long time,
- it would actually reconnect to the wifi after resume,
- I could successfully ping the PCs on the LAN,
- I could not ping anything outside the LAN, and could not connect to the Internet.
- (very strange) after having restarted the drive manually once (see fix below) this issue would have gone. I could suspend and resume and the wifi would work without having to restart the driver a second time. In order to reproduce the issue, I had to reboot, and suspend again.

Restarting the network manager (`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`) would not fix the issue. Stopping it, waiting for some time, and starting it again would not fix it either.

### Manual fix

To fix manually, I had to:

- determine my wifi driver:

  ```
  $ sudo lshw -C network
    *-network
         description: Wireless interface
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
         logical name: wlp58s0
         version: 78
         serial: 00:e1:8c:dc:8c:7d
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
         configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-43-generic firmware=31.560484.0 ip=192.168.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
         resources: irq:128 memory:ec100000-ec101fff
  ```
- restart the driver:

  ```
  $ sudo /sbin/modprobe -r iwlwifi
  $ sudo /sbin/modprobe iwlwifi
  ```

### Automatic fix

To automatically restart the driver after system resume, I did somethings similar to

[WiFi signal icon switches to Ethernet icon (up down arrows) after Suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898297/wifi-signal-icon-switches-to-ethernet-icon-up-down-arrows-after-suspend/899304#899304)

that is, I created the following script `iwlwifi-reset` in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`, and made it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh

# NAME: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/iwlwifi-reset
# DESC: Resets Intel WiFi after suspend.
# DATE: Jun 3, 2018.

MYNAME=$0

restart_wifi() {
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi BEGIN'
    /sbin/modprobe -r iwlwifi
    /sbin/modprobe iwlwifi
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_wifi END'
}

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1}' ]'
case "${1}/${2}" in
    hibernate|suspend|pre*)
        ;;
    resume|thaw|post*)
        restart_wifi;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, to get the script to be called upon system resume, I had to do the following additional steps (I'm using an old Edimax USB WiFi adaptor, so I named the **`/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`** script **`edimax_wifi_wakeup`**):

- Create a "service" file: **`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/sleep-resume.service`**
- Its contents:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Edimax USB WiFi system suspend/resume handling
  Before=sleep.target
  StopWhenUnneeded=yes

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  RemainAfterExit=yes
  ExecStart=-/lib/systemd/system-sleep/edimax_wifi_wakeup suspend
  ExecStop=-/lib/systemd/system-sleep/edimax_wifi_wakeup resume

  [Install]
  WantedBy=sleep.target
  ```
- Enable the service by **`sudo systemctl enable sleep-resume`**

Answer (score 0):

This on, after several different workarounds worked for me either: including the correct representation of WIFI network SSID, the icon of the WIFI net (not the Ethernet one in its place) the color of the icon (showing "connected" and not blank). Thanks indeed.

The only suggestion, in order to search for the implied drive, for who know and use it:

```
$ inxi -i
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82566MM Gigabit Network driver: e1000e 
  IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k 
  IF: wls3 state: up mac: 00:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy 
  IP v4: 192.168.188.144/24 type: dynamic scope: global 
  IP v6: fe80::abf3:8fd0:3e74:915f/64 scope: link 
  WAN IP: 5.90.33.85
```

a lot simpler, immediate and full of other features.