# 18.04 MSI GS65 wifi hardware switch disabled after suspend

Tags: 18.04, msi, wifi-hardware-switch

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on MSI GS65, running into what seems to be a persisting age old issue:

WIFI IS DISABLED BY HARDWARE SWITCH AFTER SUSPEND

only can comeback up after reboot.

`sudo rfkill list all` shows

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I've tried the following methods so far, and nothing has worked for me

1. Hitting the fn+f10 (f10 has a airplane icon on it) doesn't work
2. `rfkill unblock all`
3. I only tried manually restart network manager service as described in this post. Did not implement the script since it didn't work manually
   [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)
4. tried black listing the msi_wmi module as described in this post [How to unblock something listed in rfkill?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill)
5. manually restart the driver as described in this post. I didn't try the script because it didn't work manually. And also because there isn't anymore folders after my /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ . I'm pretty new to ubuntu, so I wasn't sure what to do. [(Yet another) Wifi issue after suspend in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949389/yet-another-wifi-issue-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, however had the same problem. I found the solution. Essentially enabling the airplane mode key on my system.

credit to Gibbsoft 
[Wifi Hard Blocked After Suspend in Ubuntu on GS65](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043547/wifi-hard-blocked-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-on-gs65/1058248#1058248)

1. $sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2. add to the bottom of the file and save

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' quiet splash"`
3. $sudo update-grub
4. reboot

now i press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f10</kbd> (airplane mode key) to enable wifi after suspend

Comment: Still after the wake up I have to press "Airplane mode" two times. Thanks, It is ok as a workaround, however I'll will look around for another solution.

Comment: An alternative that I found was good was using hibernate instead of suspend. I dont get this problem if i use hibernate. I followed this [guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-10/) to enable hibernate for me

Answer (score 1):

If anybody stumbles upon this and has a dual-boot Windows 10 GS65, these instructions may not work. These instructions are meant for GRUB, I setup my laptop to boot using EFI.

Try

```
sudo kernelstub -a "acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2009\""
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate a bit on what is does? Plus `kernelstub` is not installed by default, could you give instruction as to how to install it? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I got an error from grub when I did this on Ubuntu 20.04, but escaped double-quotes worked.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2009\" quiet splash"`