# PPTP VPN stops working after disconnected once

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, suspend, vpn, pptp

I am using PPTP VPN connection on Ubuntu 16.04 and it is working fine after fresh boot and when I first establish connection. But if it get disconnected by some reason and I reconnect (it reports it reconnected successfully) it stops working - meaning I can not open any web page anymore, I get timeout for all connections.

I found temporary solution by restarting network manager as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade/761220#761220)

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

This behaviour only started recently, like 2 weeks ago (maybe bug in one of the updates?), before I had no problems. VPN connection itself is not problematic since it works without problems on different OSs.

Same problem happens if I suspend and resume.

How can I debug and resolve this issue?

Comment: This may be related to an existing bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1639776 - which is "Fixed" in Zesty and has fixes pending in Xenial and Yakkety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to me as well (except with OpenVPN), and to fix it I used sudo killall dnsmasq. Unfortunately I have to do it every time I disconnect and reconnect to my vpn but its better than nothing!

EDIT: I found a solution. Go to the terminal and type

gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

And comment out the line dns = dnsmasq

Here is the link for where I found this information
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1633912

Answer (score 0):

I came cross the exactly same problem after upgrading my Ubuntu 16.04.

I also found that the "disconnect VPN" button has disappeared after upgrade and "configure VPN" has become constantly gray.

At first i doubt if there's any issue with the NetworkManager package, thus i tried reinstalling all nm packages, but it didn't work.

Then i doubt if my system is corrupted, I even reinstalled the whole OS (only root folder) with newest stable release 16.04.02, but it neither worked.

I suspect that some update in 16.04.02 caused this problem.
Really hope this problem could be solved soon.