# Wifi not showing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, rtl8723be

My laptop stopped showing wifi after i restarted it.
I tried restarted network manager but it didn't work.
It do not work even after restarting.

lshw -C network Output

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:94100000-94103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0a
       serial: b0:5a:da:d9:ab:8d
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u6
       serial: 02:35:66:51:5a:04
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-
```

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Exec format error @chili555

Comment: Did you compile the driver from source code or git? May we see: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)

Comment: @chili555 Yeah i compiled from git and followed this answer too, but but didn't fixed my problem.
sudo dkms status   OUTPUT : https://pastebin.com/ssqUUes3

Comment: @An0n that doesn't seems to be my problem. It is not even showing after restart for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from your paste, we see that you have **twenty** kernel versions installed. It won’t be long until your /boot directory is completely full and then you will be unable to install or remove anything. I suggest that you remove all but three:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot. Is your wireless working now? I doubt that it will be, so please continue.

We are going to remove and then reinstall the driver.

```
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.10 --all
sudo dkms add rtlwifi-new/0.10
sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.10
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.10
```

Take note of and post any errors. Test:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Is your wireless working now?

**EDIT**: Let’s try a newer version of rtlwifi-new.

Please do:

```
sudo updatedb
locate rtlwifi_new
```

Wherever the file was downloaded, Downloads, Desktop or some other, we will remove it:

```
sudo rm -rf rtlwifi_new
```

Now we remove the faulty dkms module:

```
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.10 --all
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/rtlwifi*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi*
```

Now we download a newer fresh version:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

If there are no errors, try to load the module:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Any improvement?

Comment: I wonder what percentage of users have a separate `/boot` partition? I only have one `/` partition that is 47% full. Of the 20 GiB of files, 10 GiB is used by **twenty-five** kernels. Therefore I'd have to hit **fifty** kernels before disk full. Not criticizing your answer in any way at all--you are the undisputed king of networking. I'm only commenting on my system differences.

Comment: Wifi isn't working. **sudo modprobe rtl8723be** gave the same error **modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Exec format error** again.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: After installing **sudo modprobe rtl8723be** gave same Exex format error and sudo dkms status gave me https://pastebin.com/Cc52iDtn

Comment: Please start again at my edit. I added some steps. Be certain that you remove everything, including what you just cloned yesterday, before you go on to the next steps.

Comment: Its still not working. When i dkms install i get this : https://pastebin.com/Q1bNM6Y7
**Running dmks install with --force will help?**

Comment: Looks fine so far. How about: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be` ?

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Exec format error again

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest. I went so far as to download and burn the iso for Ubuntu 16.04.1 which runs kernel version 4.4.0-xx. I followed the process above and here is what I get: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6R2FQxTjwb/ As you can see, the module loads without error and it's confirmed in `lsmod`. Can you run the entire process again and capture the output and give us a paste? Maybe we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/evuaXA1W
Complete paste after following above procedure.