# After suspend on HP laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 wifi adapter is not detected

Tags: networking, suspend

When my HP laptop wakes up from suspend I can't connect to the wi-fi. The adapter is lost.

`ifconfig -a` doesn't show it

`lshw -C network` returns an empty list

Only reboot helps.

Ubuntu 16.04, 4.18.5-041805-generic (I've tried on different kernels and the problem is the same).

None of the answers to [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade) help me.

wireless info before suspend (wifi work) https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr6e0nhjgtkknnb/wireless-info-before.txt?dl=0

wireless info after suspend https://www.dropbox.com/s/matik0fv28sow24/wireless-info.txt?dl=0

Comment: nothing of this helps, any other solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Have you tried *all of them?* especially [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/893823/344926) if yes: please [edit] your question and provide some more info on what went wrong where.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried all and nothing, wifi still down after suspend

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) both *before* and after wake-up from suspension (to allow a comparison between the working and non-working state) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.

Comment: wireless info before suspend (wifi work) https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr6e0nhjgtkknnb/wireless-info-before.txt?dl=0

wireless info after suspend https://www.dropbox.com/s/matik0fv28sow24/wireless-info.txt?dl=0 

can you help me?